# Generate and pass vector of 30 backticked years into function that uses NSE (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, purrr, rlang

I have the below function that takes a dataframe, and a year to filter by. I want to execute this function to return dataframes for every year from 1997 - 2017, and then I want to store all 30 frames into a single list. How do I pass in all years when my variable names are numbers that are backticked, like `2012`, `2013`, etc.?

I know I should use some variant of `lapply` or the `purrr::map` functions to get the list, but how can I pass in something like the vector `1997:2017`, but in the form of quoted expressions?

```
 # Data frame, condensed just to years 1997 to 2001 for sample code. 
df <- tibble(Asset = c("048 (NC4), LY", "059-3D, LY", "059-5F, LY"), 
                     `1997` = c(1, 1, 1), `1998` = c(1, 0, 1), `1999` = c(0, 1, 1), 
                     `2000` = c(0, 0, 1), `2001` = c(1, 1, 0), CELL_ID = c(174625, 170318, 170318))

# Returns dataframe with counts for single year
f <- function (tbl, year) {
        year <- enquo(year)
        tbl %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(CELL_ID) %>% filter(!!year == 1) %>%
          count(!!year) %>% arrange(desc(n))
        # function returns a table with counts by cell
      }

> f(df, `2001`)       
#> A tibble: 2 x 3
#> Groups:   CELL_ID [2]
#>  CELL_ID `2001`     n
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1  170318      1     1
#> 2  174625      1     1
```

What I want, pseudocoded:

```
# I've written the purrr::map call incorrectly here, 
# but here's essentially the structure for how I want to run the       
# function across years and return a list of dataframes for every year:

df %>% map_dfc(~ f(tbl = .x, year = list(`1997`, `1998`)))
#                           ^replaced w vec, or `1997`, `1998`, ... `2017`

# Assuming I fix the above call's syntax, the function I need most:
yearVec <- generateBacktickVector(1997:2017)
df %>% map_dfc(~ f(tbl = .x, year = yearVec))
```

Comment: Not sure about the tidyverse calls, but base R's `by` and `split` does just what you need. But these require data in long format (i.e., one *year* column) not wide as you have it.

Comment: This worked for my purposes, so I used `split` instead, thanks

Comment: @Parfait or ddheart, can you please expand your comments into an answer, so it can be upvoted and accepted?

Comment: I could but it was more of a helpful workaround than an answer to the original question asked. I was asking about handling NSE / backticked numbers with dplyr in R. (super grateful, but it's maybe less relevant to someone reading that title seeking help on the issue).

Comment: ^agnostic to / independent from whether the different approach using `split` is better or not

Comment: @ddheart Gotcha. From your comment, it seemed that you were happy with the `split` solution. I added the NSE / rlang counterpart as an answer below.

Comment: Yes for sure @Parfait's response was perfect for me in fact. I've just had some answers (like just updating a package version) denied before because the question was technically different/not answered. Could be wrong, and I wanted to accept Parfait's solution but I think the site/mods/users prefer I accept more targeted solutions rather than workarounds, for the encyclopedic benefit. Thanks Artem I'll check it out asap.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, simply reshape your wide data frame to long using `tidy::gather` which can take backticked names even with ranges.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

long_df <- df %>% 
  gather(key="year", value="value", `1997`:`2001`) %>%
  filter(value > 0)

long_df
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    Asset         CELL_ID year  value
#    <chr>           <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#  1 048 (NC4), LY 174625. 1997     1.
#  2 059-3D, LY    170318. 1997     1.
#  3 059-5F, LY    170318. 1997     1.
#  4 048 (NC4), LY 174625. 1998     1.
#  5 059-5F, LY    170318. 1998     1.
#  6 059-3D, LY    170318. 1999     1.
#  7 059-5F, LY    170318. 1999     1.
#  8 059-5F, LY    170318. 2000     1.
#  9 048 (NC4), LY 174625. 2001     1.
# 10 059-3D, LY    170318. 2001     1.
```

Then use `base::split` on the *year* column for your named list of data frames.

```
tibble_list <- split(long_df, long_df$year)

tibble_list 
# $`1997`
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Asset         CELL_ID year  value
#   <chr>           <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 048 (NC4), LY 174625. 1997     1.
# 2 059-3D, LY    170318. 1997     1.
# 3 059-5F, LY    170318. 1997     1.

# $`1998`
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Asset         CELL_ID year  value
#   <chr>           <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 048 (NC4), LY 174625. 1998     1.
# 2 059-5F, LY    170318. 1998     1.

# $`1999`
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Asset      CELL_ID year  value
#   <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 059-3D, LY 170318. 1999     1.
# 2 059-5F, LY 170318. 1999     1.

# $`2000`
# # A tibble: 1 x 4
#   Asset      CELL_ID year  value
#   <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 059-5F, LY 170318. 2000     1.

# $`2001`
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Asset         CELL_ID year  value
#   <chr>           <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 048 (NC4), LY 174625. 2001     1.
# 2 059-3D, LY    170318. 2001     1.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rlang` functionality you're looking for is `rlang::sym()` (and its vectorized version `rlang::syms()`), which converts strings to backticked symbols.

```
rlang::syms( as.character(1997:2001) ) %>% map( ~f(tbl = df, year = !!.x) )
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   CELL_ID [2]
#   CELL_ID `1997`     n
#     <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
# 1  170318      1     2
# 2  174625      1     1
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   CELL_ID [2]
#   CELL_ID `1998`     n
#     <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
# 1  170318      1     1
# 2  174625      1     1
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
# # Groups:   CELL_ID [1]
#   CELL_ID `1999`     n
#     <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
# 1  170318      1     2
# 
# ...
```

Note that `map_dfc` will not work, because your resulting data frames have a different number of rows.